# How to round a number to the nearest 9 in Ruby

Tags: ruby

How would I round a number to the nearest 9 in Ruby?

My desired effect is if a number is say `22.22` it would round down to `19`. If a number was `26.34` it would round to `29`

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, the round() methods for float don't have much syntactic sugar for rounding to other than the nearest integer.  One can build one's own methods—

This method assumes all the numbers are positive.  For readability, I advise you wrap this convoluted numerical calculation into a method whose name refers to what it's doing.

```
def round_to_nearest_9(num)
  ((num + 1) / 10).round * 10 - 1
end
```

If you don't want to assume the input number is positive:

```
def round_to_nearest_9(num)
  if num < 0
    return ((num - 1) / 10).round * 10 + 1
  else
    return ((num + 1) / 10).round * 10 - 1
  end
end
```

Comment: Alternatively, `(((num.abs+1) /10).round*10-1).tap { |x| x = -x if num < 0) }`.